# Notificação ao Abrir o Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Atualmente o Facebook dispara notificações ao abrir o chrome. Como posso fazer a mesma coisa, ou seja, disparar uma notificação assim que o usuário abrir o chrome?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse post: [Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/web-notifications-api/).

Comment: Eu precisava disso só que quando o usuário abre o Chrome que nem o Facebook faz.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, existe uma API para os navegadores exibirem notificações.
Essas notificações são criadas via javascript. Abaixo contém exêmplos de utilização da API.

```
if (("Notification" in window)) {
//Verifica se o navegador tem suporte à notificações

if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
//Verifica se a permissão foi concedida pelo usuário

Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
//Requisita permissão para o usuário

var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
//Envia notificação
```

Para aprofundar nesse assunto, deixei abaixo alguns links das documentações:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/notificacoes
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/

Comment: Isso serve pro chrome? o link redireciona para firefox...

Comment: Serve pro chrome, mas não serve para o que eu preciso, pois preciso que as notificações ocorram quando o chrome for iniciado. Igual o Facebook tem feito. :(

Comment: Para isso você precisará usar service workers e criar push notifications.
Segue link relativo à API do Chrome.

Comment: Segue link, [https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/]

Comment: Franco, eu sugiro que edite a resposta com o link que você acabou de postar.

Comment: @diegofm Alterado